# Вопрос по спискам в Python

Tags: python

Есть следующий код, выводит список установленных программ в Винде

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вывод у него следующий

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать, чтобы выводило только определенную программу? Например, тот же Notepad++ с версией вместе

Comment: Обратиться к тому, кто написал программу.

Comment: Приведите код и вывод в текстовом виде

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Замените цикл вывода на следующий код:

```
#В эту переменную вводите искомое приложение
prog_name = 'Notepad++ (32-bit x86)'
for software in software_list:
    if software['name'] == prog_name:
        print('Name=%s Version=%s Publisher=%s' % (software['name'], software['version'], software['publisher']))
```